# Different coloured text bubbles

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

I sent a text message from my iPhone 7 Plus this morning and in the green bubble it only shows a portion of the message and then has a forward arrow (>). If I click on the message, it takes me to a white screen with the full message.

Would this be because the message was quite long??

Comment: Exactly how long was the message? It is possible it was sent via MMS, instead of the usual SMS if it exceeded maximum character count.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) If possible, can you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/324738/edit) your question to include a screenshot?